# 500 Internal Server Error at laravel ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I developed simple form to increase or decrease value of quantity of product with laravel 5.2 ajax 
[image]

This is view ajax_help.blade.php

```
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>


    <form name="cart_form">

          {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" class="item_id" value="1">

    <div class="cart_quantity_button">
        <button type="button" class="cart_quantity_up"  data-increase="1" > + </button>
        <input class="cart_quantity_input" type="text" name="quantity" value="1" autocomplete="off" size="2">
        <button class="cart_quantity_down"  data-increase="0"> - </button>
    </div>
</form>



    <script>


    $('.cart_quantity_up,.cart_quantity_down').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
       // url = $this.data('route'),
        increase = $this.data('increase');
    updateQty(increase);
});    
        function updateQty( increase){         
     var $qty = $('.cart_quantity_input'),
        itemId = $('.item_id').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'cartajax',
        dataType: 'json', 
        data: {
          '_token': $('input[name="_token"]').val(),
            'cart_qty': $qty.val(),
            'item_id': itemId,
            'increase': increase
        },

        success:function(data){
            $qty.val(data.qty);
        }
    });
}

    </script>

    </body>
```

This is controller function ajax

```
public function ajax(Request $request){


   if ($request->ajax()) {
              $id = $request->item_id;

             $rowId = Cart::search(array('id' => $id));
             $item = Cart::get($rowId[0]);

             if ($request->increase) {

                 $n_qty = $item->qty + 1;



             } else {

                 $n_qty = $item->qty - 1;
             }

             Cart::update($rowId[0], $n_qty);

             return response()->json(['nqty' => $n_qty]);
   }
        }
```

This  is routes

```
Route::get('/ajax',function(){return view('ajax_help');});
Route::Post('/cartajax','front@ajax');
```

But I get 500 Internal Server Error.
This is my log console
**

1. POST cartajax 500 Internal Server Error 191ms
   HeadersPostResponseHTML Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
   _token  dKPRqSCprsNYhdtvsVJvX25hKsXZGS384mriDRAr cart_qty   1 increase  1 item_id   1 Source
   _token=dKPRqSCprsNYhdtvsVJvX25hKsXZGS384mriDRAr&cart_qty=1&item_id=1&increase=1

**

Please anyone help me

Comment: Check your logs...

Comment: This is my console   POST cartajax
500 Internal Server Error
4458ms 
HeadersPostResponseHTML
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
_token dKPRqSCprsNYhdtvsVJvX25hKsXZGS384mriDRAr
cart_qty 1
increase 1
item_id 1
Source
_token=dKPRqSCprsNYhdtvsVJvX25hKsXZGS384mriDRAr&cart_qty=1&item_id=1&increase=1

Comment: If you use the Chrome developer tools, go to network, click on XHR, and submit an ajax request, you should be able to see the stack trace response that laravel creates for your 500 error. Clicking on preview will display the stack trace in the normal view.

Comment: Iam using firebug lite tool  .How to trace on it?

Comment: not sure with firebug lite. chrome dev tools should display what the laravel stack trace is mentioned in last comment.

Comment: Ok i am using google chrome.are you mean install chrome dev tool?

Comment: Browser should have dev tool built in. Pushing F12 on keyboard should bring it up, or go to the browser menu > more tools > developer tools.

Comment: can we complete on chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117495/discussion-between-azhar-nabil-and-andrew-nolan).